# How to access array element inside the Hashes if the value of Hash is an array itself?

Tags: hash

Example Hash name is 
%test = { fruit => (banana apple mango litchi)
} 
so how to access the fruit mango directly??

I know 1 approach like converting the values back to array:
   @fruits = split (" ", $test{$fruits});

Please tell if there is any other approach?

Comment: What language is this? Add an appropriate tag

Comment: The hash is an array of what? In what language? If this question was asked as is to you then it is obviously in order to make you ask this questions.